# Google Colab : Copy Large .zip file to colab VM error

Tags: google-colaboratory

I had a large .zip file (~9GB) in google drive. Then, I mounted the drive to colab and I would like to copy the file to google colab VM.

the command:

```
!cp "/content/drive/My Drive/np_data.zip"  "/content/data.zip"
```

Error shown:

```
cp: error reading '/content/drive/My Drive/np_data.zip': Operation canceled
```

The error doesn't show when the first day that I tested, but the day after, the error occur and never stop.

How this can be fixed??

Answer (score 1):

If you cannot copy through mount. You can use `gdown` instead

- Share the file publicly, and get the url like `https://drive.google.com/open?id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`
- Call gdown with `gdown --id xxxxxxxxxxxxxx`

The big file can then be downloaded to the current directory.